# Connecting Qt Designer GUI to python code in QGIS Plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am creating a Plugin for QGIS 3.10 and have made a (big?) mistake.
I started by creating the whole GUI in Qt Designer and the corresponding code in Qt Creator with C++.
Now I have realized that I need that code in Python to use it in QGIS. I am completely lost now, cause I need to finish this project soon for my studies.
As far as I understand, I need to rewrite my plugin from C++ to python now. If there is an other way, i would take that too.

Until now I only managed to use my GUI for the python plugin.
[image]

here is a part of my original programm code from "mainwindow.h"

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }

QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_tabWidget_currentChanged(int index);

    void on_pushButton_schliessen_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_speichern_clicked();

    void on_button_suchen_clicked();


    void on_pushButton_loeschen_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

and my "mainwindow.cpp"

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlDriver>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QMessageBox>

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");

QString suche;
QVariant null;


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    db.setHostName("myHost");
    db.setDatabaseName("myDatabase");
    db.setUserName("myUser");
    db.setPassword("myPassword");

    if(db.open())
    {
        qDebug() <<"Database opened" ;
        db.close();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() <<"Database couldnt be opened: " + db.lastError().text();
        exit(1);
    }

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_tabWidget_currentChanged(int index)
{

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_schliessen_clicked() //close
{
    close();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_speichern_clicked() //save Database changes
{
    db.open();
    suche = ui->edit_b_nr_lon->text();
    q.prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id=:id");
    q.bindValue(":id", suche);
    q.exec();
```

See as you could see, i am developing a GUI for working with a Database. The problem now is that I don't know how to addres these buttons, input fields, etc. in the .py files shown below.

program_dialog.py

```
import os

from qgis.PyQt import uic
from qgis.PyQt import QtWidgets

# This loads your .ui file so that PyQt can populate your plugin with the elements from Qt Designer
FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'baumkataster_dialog_base.ui'))


class BaumkatasterDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(BaumkatasterDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer through FORM_CLASS.
        # After self.setupUi() you can access any designer object by doing
        # self.<objectname>, and you can use autoconnect slots - see
        # http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html
        # #widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect
        self.setupUi(self)
```

and program.py

```
class Baumkataster:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.



        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """


        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'Baumkataster_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&Baumkataster')

        # Check if plugin was started the first time in current QGIS session
        # Must be set in initGui() to survive plugin reloads
        self.first_start = None

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Baumkataster', message)


    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

        :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
            path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
        :type icon_path: str

        :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
        :type text: str

        :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
        :type callback: function

        :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
            by default. Defaults to True.
        :type enabled_flag: bool

        :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_menu: bool

        :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_toolbar: bool

        :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
            hovers over the action.
        :type status_tip: str

        :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
        :type parent: QWidget

        :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
            mouse pointer hovers over the action.

        :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
            added to self.actions list.
        :rtype: QAction
        """

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            # Adds plugin icon to Plugins toolbar
            self.iface.addToolBarIcon(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToDatabaseMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ':/plugins/baumkataster/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u''),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

        # will be set False in run()
        self.first_start = True

    def unload(self):
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginDatabaseMenu(
                self.tr(u'&Baumkataster'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)

    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""

        # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
        # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
        if self.first_start == True:
            self.first_start = False
            self.dlg = BaumkatasterDialog()

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            pass
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
```

these 2 documents where build by the QGIS Plugin Builder. Like i said, i already managed to put my qt creator ui in the corresponding .ui for the .py files.

Now i need some help on how to adress anything from my .ui in the .py.

i would be a good start to get my `"pushButton_suchen"` to make a console output in QGIS. like `"print ("Some output")"`

Comment: Did you work through - https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/building_a_python_plugin.html - before you started?

Comment: yea but a few month ago. then i started to work on my plugin. somehow i managed to completely misunderstand somtething and made my programm in qt with c++. i tried create a new plugin but even there, i am not able adress the GUI elements...

Answer (score 5):

you should connect all your buttons to functions before showing the dialog. you can use the function myFunction_suchen to print something for the beginning...:

```
    if self.first_start == True:
        self.first_start = False
        self.dlg = BaumkatasterDialog()

    # Signale und Slots verknuepfen
    self.dlg.pushButton_schliessen.clicked.connect(self.myFunction_schliessen)
    self.dlg.pushButton_suchen.clicked.connect(self.myFunction_suchen)
    self.dlg.listWidget_Listsomething.doubleClicked.connect(self.doSomething_with the_list_item)
    # and so on
    
   # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
```

Comment: Finally, i get some sort of output. Thanks a lot!!! I hope i get the rest now on my own